# TikZ Arrow ignores rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, tikz-node, shapes

I want to illustrate several arrows, each pointing to the previous arrow, except at some point, two arrows should point to the previous arrow and therefore their angle should be +/-45°. Now the problem is, that the arrow-rotation seems to lock in at multiples of 90°, which is not practical for me.

[image]

I define and use the `rotate border`, as found in the pgfmanual, but without `shape border uses incircle` as it would make the arrows [very ugly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfv5o.png) (though as can be seen, the rotation is correct).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill=green, minimum width = 30pt, ultra thick},rotate border/.style={shape border rotate=#1}]
    \node[minimum height = 30pt] (last) at (-2,0){0};% top color=vir6, bottom color=vir8,
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {1};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {2};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {...};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {1546000};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 200,anchor = tip] (orig) at (last.before tail) {1546001};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 160,anchor = tip] (fork) at (last.after tail) {1546001};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that the best way to achieve this is the following:

- Use `rotate border=180` to get the head of the arrow in the right direction
- Then apply an additional rotation by using `rotate = +/-20` to rotate node including the text.

Using only rotate would lead to the text of the node being upside-down.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill=green, minimum width = 30pt, ultra thick},rotate border/.style={shape border rotate=#1}]
    \node[minimum height = 30pt] (last) at (-2,0){0};% top color=vir6, bottom color=vir8,
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {1};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {2};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {...};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180,anchor = tip] (last) at (last.east) {1546000};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180, rotate = 20,anchor = tip] (orig) at (last.before tail) {1546001};
    \node[minimum height = 40pt,single arrow, rotate border = 180, rotate = -20,anchor = tip] (fork) at (last.after tail) {1546001};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

with use of `tikz` library `positioning` and define style for arrows you can make code much shorter and clear:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1pt,% 0pt ?
Arr/.style = {single arrow, fill=green,
                     minimum width = 30pt, outer sep=0pt,
                     anchor = tip, shape border rotate=180},
box/.style = {fill=green, minimum size=30pt}
                        ]
    \node[box] (last) {0};% top color=vir6, bottom color=vir8,
    \node[Arr, right=of last]   (a1) {1};
    \node[Arr, right=of a1]     (a2) {2};
    \node[Arr, right=of a2]     (a3) {\dots};
    \node[Arr, right=of a3]     (a4) {1546000};
    \node[Arr, rotate= 30,right=of a4.before tail]  {1546001};
    \node[Arr, rotate=-30,right=of a4.after tail]   {1546001};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]